# Android Studio freezes with Boost files in jni

Tags: android-studio, boost

I am trying to add Boost c++ files into my jni directory in Android Studio 2.1.1.  However, as you can imagine, Boost is gigantic.  Therefore, when I move the boost folder into my jni folder, my AS freezes.  I keep having to force-close AS.  Is there a better way to include Boost in your Android project?

Comment: Can't you just set an appropriate include path?

Comment: @DanMašek You mean in **Android.mk**?

Comment: I [suppose so](https://www.google.cz/search?q=android+studio+c%2B%2B+include+path). I'm not familiar with intricacies of Android Studio, but presumably it should be possible to just point the compiler to location of the header files without having to include all the files in the actual project.